# When was the RCX 2.0 released?

Tags: history, rcx

I know that the original RCX was released in 1998 and the NXT was released in 2006, but when was the RCX revision 2.0 released?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Brickset](http://brickset.com/sets/3804-1/Robotics-Invention-System-V2-0) and [Peeron](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/3804-1), it was released in 2001.